# do not appear the key color in R using heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap

The `keycolor` of my data do not appear, not really matters what I do.

The commands that I used are as follows:

**1)**

```
heatmap.2(data.matrix(sustratos),Rowv=FALSE, Colv=TRUE, 
 trace="none", ylab="Family Level",density.info = "none", 
 margins=c(9,21), col=scalebluered)
```

**2)**

```
heatmap.2(data.matrix(bacterialphyla),Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE, 
 trace="none", ylab="Bacterial Families >1%",
 density.info = "density", key = TRUE, keysize = 1.5,
 margins=c(9,18), col=scalebluered).
```

I´ve proved all the options and just do not appear the key color.

Comment: can you add sample data

Comment: You mean the color key? What is `scalebluered`?

Answer (score 0):

you can deal with change key=TRUE to FALSE

The code can be expressed as,

```
heatmap.2(data.matrix(bacterialphyla),Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE, 
 trace="none", ylab="Bacterial Families >1%",
 density.info = "density", key = FALSE, keysize = 1.5,
 margins=c(9,18), col=scalebluered).
```